# Laravel 5.5 - Update Redis Cache without expiration time

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, laravel-5.5

I want to update the value without specifying an expiration time or removing the item from the cache and store it again. I tried it this way:

After create:

```
Cache::put('post' . $id, $post, 10);
```

After update:

```
Cache::put('post' . $id, $post);
```

However, it will not be updated without an expiration time.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to overwrite a value without including the number of minutes. However, a possible work around would be to store the date and time along with your post and add logic to adjust as needed.

Create example:

```
Cache::put('post' . $id, $post, 10);
Cache::put('time:post' . $id, Carbon::now(), 10);
```

Update example:

```
$time = Cache::get('time:post' . $id);
Cache::put('post' . $id, $post, $time->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()));
```

Answer (score 0):

One example more recent for Laravel 5.7:

```
function CountWeek()
{
    if (!Cache::get('count_for_week:init')) {
        Cache::put('count_for_week:init', now()->addDays(7));
        Cache::put('count_for_week:value', 1, now()->addMonth(1));
        return true;
    }

    $time = Cache::get('count_for_week:init');
    Cache::put('count_for_week:value', (Cache::get('count_for_week:value') ?? 0) + 1, $time->diffInMinutes(now()));
}
```